# MacOS disk usage for directory reported as zero

Tags: macos, unix, du

In MacOS, the reported disk usage for a directory is sometimes reported as zero e.g.

```
$ du /etc
0   /etc
```

But, how is it possible to store any directory content without any blocks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if /etc is an actual directory or symbolic link.

```
ls -al /etc
```

Demo:

```
renegade@Renegade:~$ du test
28  test
renegade@Renegade:~$ ln -s test my_link_test
renegade@Renegade:~$ du my_link_test
0   my_link_test
renegade@Renegade:~$ ls -ltr my_link_test
lrwxrwxrwx 1 renegade renegade 4 Mar 12 06:56 my_link_test -> test
renegade@Renegade:~$
```